# Drawing "walls" in ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, visualisation, arcscene

I am working on a 3D visualisation of a map displaying the population density. I'd like to visualize the density by setting the height of an area according to it's population density. Whenever I set this up in ArcScene I only get floating plateaus.

Is there a way to draw walls and make the areas stand like pillars?

[image: flying plateaus in ArcScene]

Comment: Your Question asks about ArcGIS, but the title and tags ask about QGIS, making this two questions. Please choose one environment to be the focus of this Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the extrusion property of the layer, an example is shown below, in your case you set it to your density field. Also explore the Base Heights tab for influencing extrusion.

[image: Layer property]